# Display location details popup on map using openlayers3,geoserver

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var map;
  function init() {
    map = new ol.Map({
      target: 'map',
      view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([14.145, 76.543]),
        zoom: 11
      })
    });

    // Add the WMS layer      
    var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web-map/wms',
        params: {
          'LAYERS': 'web-map:district_output',
          'TILED': false
        },
        serverType: 'geoserver'
      })
    });
    map.addLayer(layer);

    // Set up an overlay for popups
    var popup = new ol.Overlay({
      element: document.getElementById('popup'),
      map: map,
      autoPan: true,
      autoPanAnimation: {
        duration: 250
      }
    });
    map.addOverlay(popup);

    // Define what happens if popup is closed
    document.getElementById('popup-closer').onclick = function() {
      popup.setPosition(undefined);
      document.getElementById('popup-closer').blur();
      return false;
    };

    // Define event handler for clicking a feature: opens popup with feature information
    map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
      // Set up URL for WMS GetFeatureInfo request
      var url = layer.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
        evt.coordinate, map.getView().getResolution(), 'EPSG:4263', {
          'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json'
        });
      if (url) {
        // Use the reqwest JavaScript API to send request and get JSON response
        reqwest({
          url: url,
          type: 'json',
        }).then(function(data) {
          // Process JSON response 
          if (data.features.length !== 0) {
            var returnedFeature = data.features[0];
            // Set up popup for clicked feature
            document.getElementById('popup-content').innerHTML = "<b>" + returnedFeature.properties.name + "</b><br />" + returnedFeature.properties.gid;
            popup.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
          }
        })
      }
    });

  }
</script>
</head>
```

whats wrong in the above one....please let me know

Comment: I am not able to display the popup on the map only :district_output" points  are displaying

Comment: <script src="C:\Users\user\Downloads\reqwest-master\reqwest-master\reqwest.min.js"> i have added the request library.